# Subnetting network Class B possible masks for maximum 120 hosts

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, cidr

I have an Ipv4 180.3.0.0 (class B, network bits reserved - 16bits).
What are my possible subnet masks if i want my network to have at least 22 subnets and 120 maximum hosts?

I can understand that i need to give 5 bits for 22 subnets and 7 bits for 126 usable hosts but i can't undestand how when the question ask a minimum 22 subnets and a maximum 120 hosts each subnet.

What i tried so far is i tried to give certain bits to the subnet part and the others to hosts part, creating a range of possibilities but i don't see how that solves my problem.

Anyone can help me understand the logic behind this?

Comment: Network address classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years _before_ the commercial Internet in 1995) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR/ We have not had network address classes in this century. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains exactly how to subnet.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the "at least" and "maximum" constraints indicate the priority of the values: the 120 *maximum* hosts carries a bit more weight as it dictates the size of mask you will need to use even after you've satisfied the number of subnets constraint. With a /16 network it would be easy to subnet it to provide more than enough large networks. For example, you could subnet it to a /24 and get 256 subnets (which is fine given the *at least* 22 networks condition) each with 254 host addresses. However, this fails the *maximum* 120 hosts constraint. So to satisfy the scenario you must select a mask that still provides many more subnets than required but that are each smaller in size (*less* than 120 hosts).